# Accessing collection field from specific id in meteor rendered template

Tags: javascript, meteor

**UPDATE**:
I have added additional code for clarification, which is annotated with * NEW *.
I was asked to clarify what this code is doing. A series of data is inputted into a collection called `posts`. On the postsList template the code is outputted when the timeToEnable field is less than the current time, which allows us to delay posts based on a specified date using [this](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) javascript time picker. The issue I have resides in `/client/posts/post_edit.js` where I am trying to set the value of one of the pickers from data in the collection which I don't know how to retrieve in javascript but I do in html simply using {{fieldHere}} and using the postsList template helper.

Hopefully this new code and info helps.

ORIGINAL QIUESTION.

---

I have a form that submits 5 fields in a `posts` collection. I have a edit page that, auto populates the tile, and content. However I have two separate Date/Time pickers. There is a function available to me to properly **set** the Date/Time pickers with the specific `posts` data when I am on the edit page. I cant output Date/Time data the usual way using {{date}} because it is stored in a particular format `2015-05-25T17:50:00.000Z`  I have created separate fields in the collection that separates day, month, year for do so using datepicker function.

This function will allow me to set the Date picker.

```
picker.set('select', new Date(year, month, date));
```

My Issue resides in getting the year, month and date data, based on the id that the post I am editing is using. I can place them in html using {{title}}, however I don't know how I would identify the id, and grab that post in the collection, and allow me to use `picker.set` like above.

Here is my code that I think will explain best what I have so far.

**client**
`/client/posts/post_submit.js`

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form' : function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var post = {
    title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
    postContent: $(e.target).find('[name="postContent"]').val(),
    timeToEnable: new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes),
    timeDisplay : timeDisplay,
    year : year,
    month : month,
    day : day,
    hours : hours
  };

  ////console.log(post.timeToEnable);

  Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
    // display the error to the user and abort
    if (error){
      return alert(error.reason);
    }

    // show this result but route anyway
    if (result.postExists){
      alert('This link has already been posted');
    }

      Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});


  });

  }

});
```

`/client/posts/posts_list.html` * NEW *

```
<template name="postsList">
  <div class="posts page">
    {{#each posts}}
    {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

`/client/posts/post_item.html` * NEW *

```
<template name="postItem">
  {{> dashboard}}
  <article>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-content">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h3>{{timeDisplay}}</h3>
        <p>{{{postContent}}}</p>
        <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">View</a>
        {{#if ownPost}}<a class="editPost" href="{{pathFor 'postEdit'}}">Edit</a>{{/if}}


      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</template>
```

`/client/posts/posts_list.js` * NEW *

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    //return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}});
    //
    var data = new ReactiveDict();

    data.set("now", new Date());

    return Posts.find({timeToEnable: {$lt: data.get("now")}});


  }
});
```

`/client/posts/post_edit.html`

```
<template name="postEdit">

  {{> dashboard}}

  <div class="container">



  <form id="editForm">


    <div class="postTitle">
      <label class="titleLabel">Press Release Title.</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input name="title" id="title" type="text" value="{{title}}" placeholder=""/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="postTime">
      <label class="titleLabel">Pick A time to post</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="timepicker" name="" id="" type="text" value="Click for a Time to Post" placeholder=""/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="postDay">
      <label class="">Pick A Date to post</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="datepicker" name="" id="" type="text" value="Click for a Date to Post" placeholder=""/>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div>
      <div class="textarea">
        <label class="contentLabel">Press Release content.</label>


        <!-- <input name="postContent" id="postContent" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enwave has released a..."/> -->
        <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" type="text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="submit">


    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

  </div>

  <div class="deletePost">
    <a class="btn btn-danger delete" href="#">Delete post</a>

  </div>

  </form>


  </div>
</template>
```

This is where I want to retrieve the post fields for year, month, date. So I can set the picker to that date, all based off the specific post ID.

`/client/posts/post_edit.js`

**This is the crucial part I need to output the fields from the collection here based on its specified id**

```
Template.postEdit.rendered = function(){
  picker.set('select', new Date(year, month, day));
}
```

**lib**

This Route outputs code to the html when using {{title}}.

`/lib/router.js`

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id/edit', {
  name: 'postEdit',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

`lib/collections/posts.js` * NEW *

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
  update: function(userId, post) { return ownsDocument(userId, post); },
  remove: function(userId, post) { return ownsDocument(userId, post); },
});

Posts.deny({
  update: function(userId, post, fieldNames) {
    // may only edit the following two fields:
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'title', 'postContent','timeToEnable','timeDisplay','year','month','day','hours').length > 0);
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  postInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
      title: String,
      postContent: String,
      timeToEnable: Date,
      timeDisplay:String,
      year: Number,
      month: Number,
      day: Number,
      hours: Number

    });
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
      userId: user._id,
      author: user.username,
      submitted: new Date()
    });
    var postId = Posts.insert(post);
    return {
      _id: postId
    };
  }
});
```

**server**
~/server/publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  return Posts.find();
});
```

So I would like to grab the collection fields for `posts` into postEdit when the template is rendered, which will set the value of day input picker.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what is it that the code should be doing? It's not clear from your code and explanation.

Comment: @AdnanY Which part of the code, there are a lot of moving parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me in the end.

**client**
`/posts/post_edit.js`

```
Template.post_edit.rendered = function(){
var year = (postObject.year);
var month = (postObject.month) -1;
var day = (postObject.day);
var hours = (postObject.hours);

var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
var $inputTime = $('.timepicker').pickatime();


// Use the picker object directly.
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
var pickerTime = $inputTime.pickatime('picker');


picker.set('select', new Date(year, month, day));// Get on screen image
pickerTime.set('select', [hours,0]);// Get on screen image
}
```

**lib**
`/lib/router.js`

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id/edit', {
  name: 'postEdit',
  data: function() {
  postObject = Posts.findOne(this.params._id);


    return postObject;

    }
});
```